# Runtime Error 4605. This method or property is not available because a document window is not active

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I'm trying to create an appointment in Outlook, with Word VBA, based on the data provided in the userform loaded when the Word document containing the macro is opened.

I end up with a run time error when the macro executes the paste function.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim OutInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim WdApp As Word.Application
Dim OutDoc As Word.Document
Dim WdSel As Word.Selection

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(1)

If request_Form.ComboBox3.Value = "****" Then
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("recipient_Name")
    .Range.Text = "Uwe"
End With
With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("applicant_Name")
    .Range.Text = Replace(request_Form.TextBox1.Value, "_", ", ")
End With
With OutMail
    .MeetingStatus = olMeeting
    .RequiredAttendees = "@live.in"
    .Subject = request_Form.TextBox1.Value & " Work From Home"
    .Location = "Home"
    .BusyStatus = olFree
    .ReminderSet = False
    If request_Form.CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        .Start = DateValue(request_Form.TextBox2.Value) + TimeValue(request_Form.ComboBox1.Value)
        .End = DateValue(request_Form.TextBox2.Value) + TimeValue(request_Form.ComboBox2.Value)
    Else
        .AllDayEvent = True
    End If
    .Display
End With

Set OutInsp = OutMail.GetInspector
Set OutDoc = OutInsp.WordEditor
Set WdApp = OutDoc.Application
Set WdSel = WdApp.Windows(1).Selection

Documents("Home Office Request Form.docm").Range.Copy

With OutMail
    WdSel.PasteAndFormat Type:=wdFormatOriginalFormatting
End With

save_file
 MsgBox "A copy of this file has been stored in your desktop for your 
 reference.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Status Information"

End Sub
```

The program creates an appointment based on the data filled in the userform and copies the entire content in the Word document and pastes in the body of the appointment".

When `wdsel.pasteandformat` is executed it results in run time error. This error doesn't happen often so it is hard to understand what going wrong. Lets says 70% of the time it works.

Comment: Chances are that when you open Outlook it's the Outlook window which becomes active. At that moment access to the selection in the non-active Word window might become inaccessible. To cure the problem, take everything you want from Word before opening Outlook. If that doesn't cure the problem avoid the Selection object entirely as it may not be accessible itself once its window lost focus. Copy the text into memory and use that to paste into Outlook.

Comment: @Variatus Thank you so much for your comments. Unfortunately, your first suggestion didn't work out or I'm not sure If I executed that properly. Anyway your second suggestion worked like a charm. I removed the selection object completely and used the data copied into clipboard to paste into Outlook. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have an answer to your problem. Here it is.

Chances are that when you open Outlook it's the Outlook window which becomes active. At that moment access to the selection object in the non-active Word window might become inaccessible. To cure the problem, take everything you want from Word before opening Outlook. That includes copying the text into memory and use that to paste into Outlook.